# How to capitalize first letter of EACH WORD, in input type text

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keydown', '.FIRSTNAME',
        function (event) {
            if (this.selectionStart == 0 && event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 && !(event.shiftKey) && !(event.ctrlKey) && !(event.metaKey) && !(event.altKey)) {
                var $t = $(this);
                event.preventDefault();
                var char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                $t.val(char + $t.val().slice(this.selectionEnd));
                this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
            }
        });
});
```

can you use my code and edit it?

the difference is the first letter in every word...

I just want to capitalize the first letter in every word

someone help me... tnx in advance

[image]

Comment: Use style="text-transform: capitalize;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jquery this way easy capitalize first letter of EACH WORD, in input type text**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div><label>Capitalize the first letter of all words in a string: </label><input type="text" id="txt_firstCapital" name="txt_firstCapital" /></div>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 
 jQuery('#txt_firstCapital').keyup(function() 
 {
  var str = jQuery('#txt_firstCapital').val();
       
  
  var spart = str.split(" ");
  for ( var i = 0; i < spart.length; i++ )
  {
   var j = spart[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
   spart[i] = j + spart[i].substr(1);
  }
      jQuery('#txt_firstCapital').val(spart.join(" "));
 
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

No need of using the javascript. You can simply do it in CSS using `text-transform: capitalize;` like this

```html
<input type='text' name='name' class='name' style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder='Enter your name here'/>
```

Comment: OP is looking for Title case and not Capitalize

Answer (score 1):

```js
function capitalize(obj)
{
    obj.value = obj.value.split(' ').map(eachWord=>
      eachWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + eachWord.slice(1)
    ).join(' ');
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='textfield' onkeyup='capitalize(this)'>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with this function in JS

```
function firstCap(str)
{
 return str.toString().replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + 
 txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You only needed css to fix it. Add the below code in your css.

```
.FIRSTNAME{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

OR try this

```
<input type="text" id="txtval" style="text-transform:capitalize" />
```

this works

NB: There is no need of jquery for this.

Comment: the result will not be in capitalize

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilmangal/qm3do4uu/

Comment: code edited pls check